# Is there a short-cut that enables me to call the actionbar in every activity?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

So far my actionbarsherlock is customed enabled by making use of the layout and put them inside a method `showActionBar()` in the MainActivity:

```
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionitems, null);
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled (false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

Do i have to type all these manually to each activity I have created so that the actionbar will appear? I have tried extending the MainActivity from the new activity but it does not seem to work. Example:

```
public class MyWebView extends MainActivity
```

and then call the `showActionBar()` method. It states the app has stop responding.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call any method to make the ActionBar to appear. I think that SherlockActivity is responsible for this, so you only need to make your activity extend SherlockActivity.

Comment: hmm i have tried extending sherlockactivity in the new activity. but it does not work. the whole webview activity is white. when i click the phone's back button, then the customized actionbar appears. seems like they are 2 different layers.

Comment: It throws and exception? 
Can you post some code? Clicking the back button finishes the current activity, so you probably are instantiating two different activities.

Answer (score 0):

Check the theme you are aplying to the Activity in the manifest and the definition of the theme in styles.xml.

I do something like

```
<style name="SplashScreen" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    ...
 </style>
```

to remove the ActionBar.

You should to something like this or using a built in theme with this as default.